# Flutter BloC with nested data structure

Tags: flutter, nested, bloc, hierarchical, state-management

I have a nested structure, something like this:

```
List<Areas>
|-- List<Topics>
|   |-- List<Exercises>
```

This is the workflow of my app:

1. App is opened
2. Fetch `API` and display a list of `Areas`
3. The user chooses an `Area` and go to next screen
4. Fetch `API` and display a List of Topics
5. The user chooses a `Topic` and go to next screen
6. Fetch `API` and display a List of Exercises
7. User needs to complete all of them

I started using [BloC](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/) but I'm not sure if I should use a Bloc for each type of data (so one bloc for `Areas`, another for `Topics` and another for `Exercises`) or handle the whole structure in only one Bloc.

I see a problem having a `State` that contains the whole structure and needs to be updated every time a nested list is fetched from the `API`. Maybe this will cause memory problems?

On the other hand, having one Bloc per type of data will make complicated the communication between them.

I'm also opened to switch to another `state management` technique if it makes more sense.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to have one bloc per screen. So in your case it would be best to have 3 blocs. You should also keep communication between blocs to a minimum as each should have its own responsibilities.